# Unprocessable Entity error when trying to use best_in_place rails editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I am trying to use the best_in_place gem in a test app that I am running. While the best_in_place gem gets installed and gives no error while loading on page (i.e.html loads with the  etc. ), there seems to be an issue on clicking enter after modifying the user parameter through an 'input' box in the HTML view. The user input into the box does not seem to get updated into my db.

My view :

```
<%= best_in_place @user, :name %>

<%= best_in_place @user, :name, activator: "#edit_#{@user.id}", display_with: :link_to, 
 helper_options: user_path(@user) %>

<small><a href="#" id="edit_<%= @user.id %>">edit</a></small>
```

My user controller:

```
  def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find params[:id]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])

        format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully updated.') }
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@user) }
      else

        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@user) }
      end
    end
  end
```

Terminal output script while trying to run on server

```
Started PUT "/users/108" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-24 15:26:14 +0530
Processing by UsersController#update as JSON

Parameters: {"user"=>{"name"=>"ap"}, "authenticity_token"=>"3d/ZtW3csCIqXWG5Qk1U2QjMlyTQZ5W9/tBnVNZlHY8=", "id"=>"108"}

User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'VJ-EiGLCCGtqjPhuebTbZQ' LIMIT 1

User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "108"]]

CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "108"]]

   (0.1ms)  begin transaction

  User Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('b@b.com') AND "users"."id" != 108) LIMIT 1

   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 347ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
```

Ideally, I am expecting an UPDATE "users" SET ........ statement following the begin transaction in the code above. Do you recognize why my code does not update user parameters in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The JS .purr file is displaying validation error messages.
If you're using Rails 4, include it in your application.js file as follows:

```
//= require best_in_place

//= require best_in_place.purr
```

Instead of

```
//= require jquery.purr
```

as shown in the Rails Cast video: http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing?view=asciicast

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically for your @user (Which I would assume has some authentication associated with it and has it's own quirks and impact), but I found that a validates_numericality_of in my model on a variable that I couldn't validate was preventing me from saving. Once I commented that out, it saved. I had the same exact error as you beforehand.